# Add JSON key into url for specific product id

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

From a JSON response I have the data displaying where I want it but Im looking for a way to get the data for a single product rather than all of them..

I've only done basic ajax/json work before so i don't really understand how to get the look number into the url eg.. wwww.somesite.com/cat/clothes/looknumber/

```
var REMOTE_SERVICES = {
    'product-detail' : '/_ui/ajax/looks-detail-items.json',
};

return {
    config : function() {
        return REMOTE_SERVICES;
    }
};



if (lookNumber != idFound) {
 ajaxLoader.loadJson(
 URL_SERVICE,
 CONTAINER_ITEMS_LOOKS_GALLERY,
 $activeSlide,
 REMOVE_CLASS,
 lookNumber
);
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$.ajax({
        url: jsonUrl[url.toUpperCase()],
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response) {
        response = (url == 'looks-detail')? [response, look] :
            response;

        resultObject = jsonHtml.compiler(response, url);

        if (resultObject.hideButton) {
            $link.hide();
        }

        loader.loadRepsonseInContainer(
            $container,
            $(resultObject.html),
            $link,
            $('.' + removeElementsClass)
        );
    }).fail(function() {
        loader.showLoadError($container, $link);
    });
}
```

with the addition of the data.lookNumber.. but I don't understand what that does

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
suppose you have json variable named 'data'

$.ajax({
  url : "wwww.somesite.com/cat/clothes/" + data.lookNumber +"/",
  data : {...}     
});

you can use like data.lookNumber
```

Comment: what does + data.lookNumber "+"/ actually do?

Comment: data is json object and lookNumber is its property so you can fetch
using data.lookNumber and it will append to url

Comment: would I be able to add it to the url like 'product-detail' : '/_ui/ajax/" + data.lookNumber +"/looks-detail-items.json',

Comment: is that different to datatype?

Comment: I have defined the data variable: data: {data:lookNumber} but I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined